# preg_match for 7 digit id does not give expected results

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to only allow id as 7 digit numbers. I have the following code in PHP for exact match.

```
$id_pattern = "^\d{7}$";
preg_match($id_pattern, $id, $regs);
```

And I am checking in $regs[0] if I get the right id. But its not working for any number of digits. Please help.

Comment: You need delimiters...  `$id_pattern = "/^\d{7}$/";` [would work](http://3v4l.org/nicka) (and configure PHP to show you those errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$id_pattern = "/^\d{7}$/";
preg_match($id_pattern, $id, $regs);
```

You need delimiters to start/end the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing delimiters.

```
$id_pattern = "/^\d{7}$/";
```